# How to unpivot columns using CROSS APPLY in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, cross-apply

I want to use CROSS APPLY to UNPIVOT multiple columns.

The columns `CGL, CPL, EO` should become Coverage Type, the values for `CGL, CPL, EO` should go in column `Premium`, and values for `CGLTria,CPLTria,EOTria` should go in column `Tria Premium`

```
declare @TestDate table  ( 
                            QuoteGUID varchar(8000), 
                            CGL money, 
                            CGLTria money, 
                            CPL money,
                            CPLTria money,
                            EO money,
                            EOTria money
                            )

INSERT INTO @TestDate (QuoteGUID, CGL, CGLTria, CPL, CPLTria, EO, EOTria)
VALUES ('2D62B895-92B7-4A76-86AF-00138C5C8540', 2000, 160, 674, 54, 341, 0),
       ('BE7F9483-174F-4238-8931-00D09F99F398', 0, 0, 3238, 259, 0, 0),
       ('BECFB9D8-D668-4C06-9971-0108A15E1EC2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

SELECT * FROM @TestDate
```

Output:

[image]

The result should be like that :

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One quick and easy way is with `VALUES`

**Example**

```
select A.QuoteGUID
      ,B.*
 From  @TestDate A
 Cross Apply ( values ('CGL',CGL,CGLTria)
                     ,('CPL',CPL,CPLTria)
                     ,('EO',EO,EOTria)
             ) B (CoverageType,Premium,TiraPremium)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks John!

Comment: @Oleg happy to help

Comment: There's a nice article on unpivoting by Itzik Ben-Gan that includes this technique here - https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/unpivoting-data

In summation, this is the best technique.

Comment: @ChrisKoester Thanks, I agree.  The CROSS APPLY allows for lateral queries and the values () allows for a bit more flexibility and control.