# Retrieve substring of a column name, then apply them to corresponding column data? SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with, let's say, 13 columns. I need to take a part of the column name and apply it to the corresponding data in two columns.

Example of what I start with:

| Class | Result01 | Result02 | Result03 | Result04 | Result05 | Result06 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENG | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5 | data6 | ... |
| MATH |  | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5 |  | ... |

The desired result:

| Class | All_Results |
| --- | --- |
| ENG-NNN-01 | ENG-NNN-01 data1 |
| ENG-NNN-02 | ENG-NNN-01 data2 |
| ... | ... |
| MATH-NNN-02 | MATH-NNN-02 data2 |
| MATH-NNN-03 | MATH-NNN-03 data3 |
| MATH-NNN-04 | MATH-NNN-04 data4 |

I have managed to get the table displayed properly, but getting multiple col_name and applying them to the proper place is beyond me.

```
DECLARE @resultNum1 varchar(2) = SUBSTRING(COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('[TABLE_NAME]'), 20),9, 2)
DECLARE @ccOutcome varchar(4) = '-NNN'
DECLARE @class varchar (25)
SELECT CONCAT(class, @ccOutcome,'-', @resultNum1) AS 'ERP_ID', All_Results FROM [TABLE_NAME] AS tbl
UNPIVOT
(
    All_Results
    FOR outcomes IN( [Result01], [Result02], [Result03], [Result04], [Result05], [Result06], ...
)AS u
ORDER BY class;
```

Any ideas on how best to solve this?

Comment: This, in truth, looks like you need to fix your design. Having multiple Result columns is breaking one of the basic principles of normalisation. If you fix the design, you'll find that what you are trying to do is far more trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unpivot columns using CROSS APPLY in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654306/how-to-unpivot-columns-using-cross-apply-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: @Larnu I very much appreciate that feedback.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't think so but is helpful overall to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  Just a couple of tweaks.

- Replace the `@resultNm1` in your CONCAT to `RIGHT([u].[outcomes], 2)` since you want the number from each of your columns.
- Then change `All_Results` to CONCAT what you did to get your ERP_ID field with All_Results `CONCAT(CONCAT(class, @ccOutcome,'-', RIGHT([u].[outcomes], 2)), ' ', All_Results)` with a space in there.

Your query would then look like:

```
SELECT   CONCAT([Class], @ccOutcome, '-', RIGHT([u].[outcomes], 2)) AS 'ERP_ID'
       , CONCAT(CONCAT([Class], @ccOutcome, '-', RIGHT([u].[outcomes], 2)), ' ', [All_Results]) AS [All_Results]
FROM     [TABLE_NAME] AS [tbl]
    UNPIVOT (
                [All_Results]
                FOR [outcomes] IN ( [Result01], [Result02], [Result03], [Result04], [Result05], [Result06] )
            ) AS [u]
ORDER BY [u].[Class];
```

Which then should give you the following results based on your sample data:

```
ERP_ID            All_Results
----------------- ----------------------------
ENG-NNN-01        ENG-NNN-01 data1
ENG-NNN-02        ENG-NNN-02 data2
ENG-NNN-03        ENG-NNN-03 data3
ENG-NNN-04        ENG-NNN-04 data4
ENG-NNN-05        ENG-NNN-05 data5
ENG-NNN-06        ENG-NNN-06 data6
MATH-NNN-01       MATH-NNN-01 
MATH-NNN-02       MATH-NNN-02 data2
MATH-NNN-03       MATH-NNN-03 data3
MATH-NNN-04       MATH-NNN-04 data4
MATH-NNN-05       MATH-NNN-05 data5
MATH-NNN-06       MATH-NNN-06
```

I would suggest revisiting your design and what you are trying to accomplish if possible. Continuing patterns like this can cause challenges trying to get results.

Comment: Thank you! That got me to where I needed to be! I appreciate the advice about the design, as well, I need as much advice as possible. Thanks, again!